# Personal Access Token Not Authentication Failed when pulling code

Tags: github

I am trying to connect to my GitHub repo using a PAT. I followed all the steps and something weird is happening:

This command works:

```
git ls-remote https://<username>:<PAT>@github.com/<username>/<reponame>
```

But when I run ANY git command from the command line and get prompted for the username and password (and I enter the PAT instead), I get this error:

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>'
```

I have pasted the PAT on the CL and it pastes just fine. What am I missing here?? I am doing this on a Ubuntu machine.

Also `git config credential.helper` returns nothing!

Update:
After some googling, I found that Linux stores system passwords in /etc/shadow. For me, this file contains two entries : 'gitlog' and 'gitdaemon' . Could this be the reason why the PAT entry is not working?

Comment: Are you sure you're not pasting a space or some other character as part of your PAT?

Comment: Yes! I pasted it multiple times to make sure. Is there somewhere in Linux the password or the previous PAT could be stored?

Answer (score 0):

Try using it on another machine and see if it works, if so then it might have something to do with your machine but if it doesn't work on other machines, I think you might need to generate a new PAT and try again.

Comment: The trick is to earn 50 reputation so you can post comments.

Answer (score 0):

you can check your credentials using

```
git config --global --edit
```

once you are inside the config edit, follow this steps

1. Edit your Git configuration file (.gitconfig) and remove the lines containing your PAT and the extraheader configuration.
2. Ensure that the GitHub CLI is installed and properly set up on your system.
   If you are using GitHub CLI's credential helper (`gh auth git-credential`), it should handle the authentication process for you.
3. You might need to reauthenticate with GitHub CLI. You can do this by running gh auth login and following the prompts.

then git pull.